# How to implement BST searching in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
search_bst :: Tree -> String -> Maybe Int 
search_bst Leaf _ = Nothing
search_bst (Node k v l r) sk =
    if sk == k then Just v
    else if sk < k then search_bst l sk
    else search_bst r sk
```

I can get the concept but what does `Node k v l r` mean? Does it mean that `search_bst` takes two parameters, which the first one is an instance of type `Node` and has three values?

Comment: Yes; this is pattern-matching against the parameters of `Node`, in order to bind the variables for use later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature of the Haskell language is called *pattern matching*. The signature `Tree -> String -> Maybe Int` tells you that first argument of the `search_bst` function is of type `Tree`. The `Tree` data type is probably defined as follows:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node String Int Tree Tree
```

A `Tree` is either a `Leaf` or a `Node`. A `Node` also contains 4 fields of type `String`, `Int`. `Tree` and `Tree`. Pattern matching now allows you to access these fields and take apart a value of type `Tree`. In your function, the first case:

```
search_bst Leaf _ = Nothing
```

means: If `search_bst` is given a `Leaf` as first argument, and anything as second argument, return `Nothing`.

The second case:

```
search_bst (Node k v l r) sk =
  if sk == k then Just v
  else if sk < k then search_bst l sk
  else search_bst r sk
```

then means: If the the first argument of type `Tree` is a `Node`, then the variables k, v, l and r will be the values of the fields of the `Node` constructor. The variable `sk` refers to the second argument of the function.

So if you run `search_bst (Node "foo" 3 Leaf Leaf) "foo"`, what happens is that first, the first case will be tried. Because the expression `Node "foo" 3 Leaf Leaf` is a `Node` and not a `Leaf`, the first case will fail. Now the second case will be tried, and it matches. So `k` is set to `"foo"`, `v` is set to `3`, `l` to `Leaf` and `r` is also set to `Leaf`. Then the body of the function is evaluated.

You can learn more about the syntax of function definitions in a [chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) of the book Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!.

Comment: "k" for "key", "v" for "value", "l" for "left", "r" for "right.

Answer (score 3):

```
search_bst :: Tree -> String -> Maybe Int
```

means that `search_bst` takes two arguments, one of type `Tree` and one of type `String`, and produces a `Maybe Int`.

```
search_bst Leaf _ = ...
```

means: "do ... if the first argument (the one of type `Tree`) is `Leaf` (which is a value of type `Tree`). And finally

```
search_bst (Node k v l r) sk = ...
```

means "do ... if the first argument is a tree that's been constructed using the `Node` constructor and let `k`, `v`, `l` and `r` hold the values that have been given as arguments to `Node`. Also let `sk` refer to the second argument of `search_bst`.".

> Does it mean that search_bst takes two parameters, which the first one is an instance of type Node and has three values?

The first argument has type `Tree`. There likely is no type `Node` in your program (and even if there is, it has nothing to do with the `search_bst` function).

Answer (score 3):

It's important to distinguish between *types* and (value-) *constructors*. Let's consider a simpler example: you know

```
data Maybe a = Just a
             | Nothing
```

now, both `Just` and `Nothing` are *constructors* for values. These values will in either case have *type* `Maybe A`, where `A` can be any "contained type" (e.g. `Maybe Int`). `Nothing` is a nullary constructor, so it can be used on its own to construct a `Maybe` value. `Just` is a unary constructor, so it needs one argument (of the contained type).

> Prelude> Nothing    :: Maybe Int
>   Nothing
>   Prelude> Just 3     :: Maybe Int
>   Just 3

Now, the standard way to implement a function that takes a `Maybe` as its argument is to *pattern match* on those constructors. For instance,

```
showMaybe :: Maybe Int -> String
showMaybe Nothing = ""
showMaybe (Just n) = show n
```

Note that I *deconstructed* the `Just` value: I give it as many new variable names as the `Just` constructor needs for constructing, these variables then have the values of the contained data.

In your example, the data type is a bit more complicated

```
type TreeKey = String
type TreeContain = Int

data Tree = Leaf
          | Node TreeKey TreeContain Tree Tree
```

(normally, you would write `data Tree k v = Note k v (Tree k v) (Tree k v) | Node`, which works exactly the same but can use others keys/values as strings and ints.)